# Setting default icon on jstree

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, jstree

I am using jstree(with plugin types) together with bootstrap.

I am using glyphicons for specific types from bootstrap and it works well.

However when I try setting an icon for the default type I see an empty image even the Inline Style on Developer Tools(IE) says different.

Types javscript:

```
"types": {
                "default": {
                    "icon": "~/Images/icon_topicpg.png"
                },
                "moveType": {
                    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"
                },...
```

Element inspected on HTML:

```
<i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style='background-position: center; background-image: url("~/Images/icon_topicpg.png"); background-size: auto;'></i>
```

Why is the image not shown?

What should be fixed here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by setting the icon to a complete URL like following:
http://domain/app/Images/icon.png

instead of a path